# How to force renew of a Let's Encrypt Certificate in ISPConfig 3?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I'm using ISPConfig 3 and all certificates are renewing automaticly, except one. I'd disabled SSL (and Let's Encrypt) for this Website, removed the Certs in /etc/letsencrypt for that Site and enabled it again. But it's still using the old cert and not renewing it. And now the browser show that it's a not acceptable cert for this site.

How can i fix it (renew) it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:

1. Disabled Let's Encrypt for this site in ispconfig Admin Panel
2. Removed the cert and the renewal file in **/etc/letsencrypt/renewal** and **/etc/letsencrypt/certs** for this site
3. Enabled let's encrypt for the site again in ispconfig configuration.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

this is good but:
Disabled Let's Encrypt for this site in ispconfig Admin Panel

Removed the cert and the renewal file in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal and /etc/letsencrypt/certs for this site

Enabled let's encrypt for the site again in ispconfig configuration.

Previuos solution is missing for a step:

- must be remove the cert file in /etc/letsencrypt/archive and /etc/letsencrypt/live
  otherwise ispconfig create the new config file in /etc/letsencrypt/renewal be because old certificate still existing new certificate will not be generated